# How to use location listener?

Tags: android, location, android-gps

Its not clear to me how to use the location listener.

Do I do this:

```
public Location actualLocation;

private class mLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        actualLocation = location;
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }
}

//Middle of code
currentLatitude = actualLocation.getLatitude()
currentLongitude = actualLocation.getLongitude()
```

or this:

```
public Location actualLocation;

private class mLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }
}

//Middle of code
actualLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

currentLatitude = actualLocation.getLatitude()
currentLongitude = actualLocation.getLongitude()
```

There are variables used that were not declared in this snippets of code. It's on purpose. I shortened the code for the sake of simplicity.

**UPDATE:**
My question was: ¿Do I use getLastKnow location or do I manually save the location every run be it updates? ¿Would that work the same?

Comment: what do you want to achieve using LocationListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call LocationManager.registerLocationUpdates.  You pass the LocationListener into that call, and the framework will call those functions whenever it has a new location.

Comment: I updated my question now so it is more clear. I basically wanted to know if locationUpdates update the getLastKnowLocation or do I have to write the new location manually every times it updates?

Comment: Write it every time it updates. If you were to call get last known location again it would give you a new answer, but it won't update old results